# Php execution halts till file is downloaded

Tags: php

I am developing a video on demand website. Download option is provided with content headers and readfile. I'm facing a problem, I can view or download other contents only after the download of a previous file is completed. 
My current readfile code

```
session_start();
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_SESSION['file']);
//set_time_limit(0);
readfile($_SESSION['file']); 
exit();
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: I have no experience with streaming content but it might be better to use JS to do this. This is because JS with AJAX can change things on the fly which is something PHP can't

Comment: You are experiencing what is known as Session Locking.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes, now I learnt this, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the session: As long as this request is running, the session is locked so you cannot do anything that uses the same session.

A solution would be to assign the value of the filename to another variable and close the session before you output the contents to the browser.

For example:

```
session_start();
$filename = $_SESSION['file'];
// close the session
session_write_close();

// output the data
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
//set_time_limit(0);
readfile($filename); 
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. Learnt something new, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because of session locking. When you call `session_start()`, PHP locks session file so any other process can't using until lock is released. That happens in order to prevent concurrent writes.

So when the other request comes to the servers, PHP waits on `session_start()` line until it will able to use session, which is when the first request ends.

You can open session in *read only* by passing additional parameter `read_and_close`. As mentioned in [`session_start()` manual - example #4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

```
<?php
// If we know we don't need to change anything in the
// session, we can just read and close rightaway to avoid
// locking the session file and blocking other pages
session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
    'read_and_close'  => true,
]);
```

**Note:** As the manual says, the options parameter was added in PHP7. (thanks MonkeyZeus for pointing that out). In case you're using older version, you can try with `session_write_close` according to jeroen's answer.

Comment: Please mention that fact that this will only work with PHP >= 7.x because it is possible OP has a hosting provider which has not upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

Other requests are blocked, because the session file is locked by this one.
The solution is to close the session before calling `readfile` by using [session_write_close](http://php.net/session_write_close) function,

like this:

```
<?php
$file = $_SESSION['file'];
session_write_close();
readfile($file); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers are PHP-only solutions, I would like to offer the amazing power of [mod_xsendfile](https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile) with a PHP fallback:

```
session_start();

// Set some headers
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_SESSION['file']);

if(in_array('mod_xsendfile', apache_get_modules()))
{
    header("X-Sendfile: ".$_SESSION['file']);
}
else
{
    $file = $_SESSION['file'];
    // close the session
    session_write_close();


    //set_time_limit(0);
    readfile($file); 
}

exit(0);
```